# Difference between .getclass() and .forName()

Tags: java

whats the difference between .getclass() and .forName() apart from the fact that one uses object and other uses class name...
My confusion engenders from diff opinion on both of them...some say that both returns object..while some say .forname() loads the class while .getClass() returns the object
Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12337439/1144203

Comment: What makes you think there *is* a difference other than that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public final Class<?> getClass()
```

: Returns the runtime class of of the Object on which it is invoked.If an instance of an object is available, then the simplest way to get its Class is to invoke Object.getClass()

`public static Class<?> forName(String className)` :

Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

A call to `Class.forName("fullyQualifiedClassName")` causes the class to be dynamically loaded (at runtime). A call to `forName("fullyQualifiedClassName")` causes the class to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after class loading)