# NoSuchMethodException when parameter of java.lang.Integer is passed in constructor (Reflection)

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection

I am trying to declare an `ArrayList` using Reflection. Below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    String intClass="java.lang.Integer";   //This string will be replaced by a string taken from user which will be a class name.
    Class classOf=Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
    Class[] parameterslist ={Class.forName(intClass)};
    Constructor constructorOfClass=classOf.getConstructor(parameterslist);
}
```

When I run this code I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.ArrayList.<init>(java.lang.Integer)
```

When I modify parameterslist as

```
Class[] parameterslist={int.class}
```

it works but I have to take the name of parameter class as input from a user, so I can't directly write `int.class`.

I have already searched about the difference between `Class.forName()` and `Classname.class` but answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337439/distinction-between-classobject-getclass-classname-class-and-class-fornameclas) conclude that they are same.
I just want to know why we cannot use `Class.forName()` object to pass as a parameter to `ArrayList` constructor and how does it work when I write `int.class`? If `Class.forName()` is not the right way then how can we make an object of a classname taken as input from a user?

Comment: Well, there is a limited number of primitive types. If I were you I would just create a map and use the primitive types' names as keys and the corresponding `Class` objects as values.

Comment: @Sweeper you are right. That will solve the problem but still why we can't use Class.forname for this purpose?

Comment: I do not understand. You have hard-coded the classname `java.lang.Integer` into this code. Where does the user input come into it? or `Class.forName()`? The only thing wrong with `Class.forName()` here is the parameter you supplied to it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I added a comment in the code which make things more clear.

Comment: Not really. Either the user gets the class name right or he doesn't. If he doesn't, it's his fault. But I suspect in this case he *can't*, which is your fault for designing it this way. Reconsider.

Comment: @Sweeper you right. I will use your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ArrayList` constructor that you want to use takes as parameter a primitive `int` and not an `Integer` class :

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

You provide as argument the `Integer` class :

```
String intClass="java.lang.Integer";
...
Class[] parameterslist ={Class.forName(intClass)};
```

These are not compatible types for reflection usage.

> If Class.forname is not the right way than how can we make an object
>   of a classname taken as input from user.

`Class.forName()` is not the issue here.
If you want to create by reflection an object by passing an instance of a specific class as argument of the constructor, the class has to provide a constructor with this type.
For `ArrayList`, you have only two overloaded constructors with arguments :

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

and

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

So you could retrieve by reflection a constructor with a `Collection` type or an `int` type and that's all.

Comment: The OP wants to get some user input and get the `Class` object corresponding to that input. So if the user enters `int`, he wants to get `int.class`

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe. It's not evident from his actual question, or the code he posted. It's up to him to clarify, not us to guess.

Comment: @Sweeper If it is the case, it is really not clear. I most answered to the last part : "I just want to know why we cannot use `Class.forName()` object to pass as a parameter to `ArrayList` constructor and how does it work when I write `int.class`? "

Comment: @Ahsan: That's certainly not what happens on my box: `System.out.println(int.class)` prints "int". Which JVM are you using?

Comment: You are welcome. Not sure to understand. `Integer` and `int` are indeed distinct types. So `System.out.println(int.class);` prints "int" while       `System.out.println(Integer.class);` prints "class java.lang.Integer". Please check your printing tests.

Comment: @davidxxx you are right. Both give different outputs.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right. Both give different outputs